# Need an OAuth token secret to get an OAuth token secret? What the heck?

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to implement 'Sign in with Twitter', but I'm stuck at trying to work out how to get an OAuth token secret for the user.

The Twitter API docs ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter)) say:

> To start a sign in flow, your application must obtain a request token by sending a **signed message** to POST oauth/request_token
>
> ...
>
> The body of the response will contain the oauth_token, **oauth_token_secret**, and oauth_callback_confirmed parameters

And the docs for creating a signature ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)) say:

> The value which identifies the account your application is acting on behalf of is called the **oauth token secret**. This value can be obtained in several ways, all of which are described at Obtaining access tokens.

And the 'obtaining access tokens' page links back to [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter), completing the circle.

**How can I obtain a token secret if I need a token secret to sign the request to obtain the token secret?** What the heck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on creating a signature:

```
Note that there are some flows, such as when obtaining a request token, 
where the token secret is not yet known. In this case, the signing key 
should consist of the percent encoded consumer secret followed by an 
ampersand character '&'.
```

You received a **consumer secret** when you registered for an API key. This is what you want to sign with to obtain a request token.

I would highly recommend looking into using a library which implements at least the oauth basics such as signing if not a [Twitter API library](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), assuming one is available for your language of choice.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that. I don't think there are any libraries available for Python 3.3 which support 'Sign in with Twitter'.